# GridView inside UserControl RowCreated event is firing even after the UserControl is not visible anymore

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, user-controls

Here´s the scenario,

I have a Page that has a menu with 3 User Controls, only one of the UC is visible at the time. 
Every UC has it's own GridView, with it's respective RowCreated Event.
I have set 3 breakpoints one for every UC's RowCreated event.

From the Page, when i visit one of the UC, let's say **UC_A**, only it's RowCreated Event is firing which is fine. But when i visit another UC, **UC_B**,  the RowCreated Event of the **UC_A** is firing again, and after that the **UC_B**'s RowCreated event is firing which is the expected behaviour..

The only code that executes between the switch between UC's is in the Parent Page:

```
    Protected Sub dlMenu_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListCommandEventArgs)
        UC_A.Visible = false
        UC_B.Visible= true
        UC_B.LoadPrincipalPage() 'Which has no code in common with the UC_A
    End Sub
```

Note that the RowCreated event is being fired before the dlMenu_ItemCommand from Parent Page.
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the visibility in Page_Load event. Right now you are changing visibility later on in the page life cycle by which time the control that was visible initially has fired its events.

If you are doing  a regular postback, then use below method.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

Dim postbackControl As String = Page.Request.Params("__EVENTTARGET")

If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(postbackControl) AndAlso postbackControl = dlMenu.UniqueID Then
    UC_A.Visible = False
    UC_B.Visible = True
End If

End Sub
```

You can even put this code in Page_Load events of individual user controls and make the user control invisible according to the post back control.